# How to change text description that appears on Google

Tags: seo

the title pretty much covers it. How do I change the text that appears below my website's title on Google?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a descriptive meta description that matches your page's content and hope Google uses that over your text on the page. Reference:
http://webmarketingtoday.com/articles/influencing-how-google-displays-your-page-description/